# duplicated id for ids query of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I tested ids query of elasticsearch as below , instead of getting 5 results , I just got 3 unique results because we have 3 same "930147044672688594".

Is there any solution I can get 5 results even I have duplicated ids ?

```
{
"query": {
        "ids": {
            "values": ["939335337147845048", "931522394912682989", "930147044672688594","930147044672688594","930147044672688594"]
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible since you have "only" three documents with those three different ids in your index. ES will not make up artificial documents.

As you can see in the source code for the [`IdsQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/068df5f8aa5642432c77962768b17046a86ddbc4/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/IdsQueryBuilder.java#L56), internally that `ids` list is a Set, which means that each element is unique. So before being executed, your three duplicate ids are actually transformed to a set of three unique ids `["939335337147845048", "931522394912682989", "930147044672688594"]`